# How to start solr using maven?

Tags: solr, maven-3, pom.xml

I am using solr 5.3.1. Is there any way to launch solr using maven 3.1 .1 using pom.xml.

I tried ny putting solr core  in pom.xml .I could see that the solr core's jar and  jetty jar and other solr transitive dependencies getting downloaded in the folder maven dependencies under my eclipse project.But  how to launch solr using maven command?

Answer (score 1):

You can start solr as [[EmbeddedSolrServer]](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr). For that you need to add solr-core and solr-solrj dependencies as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In Java code, you need to start the solr server as EmbeddedSolrServer mode. as below.

```
    CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer(<solrHome-abosolute-path>);
    coreContainer.load();
    this.solrClient = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, <solrCore-name>);
```

Then you can use solrClient inside the project to do search and indexing operations. This can only use within the project, and there is no admin console in embedded solr mode.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_3_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html